# adding data from the user input fields to the table dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <form >

    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <select id="country" name="country">
      <option value="australia">Australia</option>
      <option value="canada">Canada</option>
      <option value="usa">USA</option>
    </select>

    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"  onclick="doFunction();">
  </form>
  </div>
  <table style="width:100%"  id = "myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>country</th>
  </tr>
    <style>

    input[type=text], select, textarea {
        width: 100%; /* Full width */
        padding: 12px; /* Some padding */
        border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Gray border */
        border-radius: 4px; /* Rounded borders */
        box-sizing: border-box; /* Make sure that padding and width stays in place */
        margin-top: 6px; /* Add a top margin */
        margin-bottom: 16px; /* Bottom margin */
        resize: vertical /* Allow the user to vertically resize the textarea (not horizontally) */
    }

    /* Style the submit button with a specific background color etc */
    input[type=submit] {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    /* When moving the mouse over the submit button, add a darker green color */
    input[type=submit]:hover {
        background-color: #45a049;
    }

    /* Add a background color and some padding around the form */
    .container {
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        padding: 20px;
    }
</style>
<script>
function doFunction(){
  var value = document.getElementById("fname").select();
  var lastname = document.getElementById("lname").select();
  var  country = document.getElementById("Country").select();
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 =  row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 =  row.insertCell(2);
  cell1.innerHTML = "value";
  cell2.innerHTML = "lastname";
  cell3. innerHTML = "country";
}
  </script>



</body>
```

we are having the empty text boxes  when the user enters the data into text box  and click the submit button the data should add into the table which we created in your html page
i used select by id tags in java script and insert row method to add the element to the table dynamically in javascript
i tryed but i  am not getting the desired output 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are these problems with your code.

- you have forgotten to close `table` tag
- you need to use `.value` not `.select()` to get value of input field
- you need to pass the obtained value stored in variable to the `innerHTML` of cells instead hard-coded string
- you need to add `event.preventDefault()` to the `submit event listener` if you don't want the page to be reloaded
- `getElementById('Country')` should be `getElementById('country')`

I have added `thead` and `tbody` to your html so that you can insert directly to table body instead of table and changed for that table to 
`var table = document.querySelector("#myTable tbody");`

```js
function doFunction(){
  var value = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var lastname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  var country = document.getElementById("country").value;
  var table = document.querySelector("#myTable tbody");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 =  row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 =  row.insertCell(2);
  cell1.innerHTML = value;
  cell2.innerHTML = lastname;
  cell3.innerHTML = country;
}

const submit = document.querySelector('#submitBtn');
submit.addEventListener('click', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  doFunction();
});
```

```css
input[type=text], select, textarea {
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  padding: 12px; /* Some padding */
  border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Gray border */
  border-radius: 4px; /* Rounded borders */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Make sure that padding and width stays in place */
  margin-top: 6px; /* Add a top margin */
  margin-bottom: 16px; /* Bottom margin */
  resize: vertical /* Allow the user to vertically resize the textarea (not horizontally) */
}

/* Style the submit button with a specific background color etc */
input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* When moving the mouse over the submit button, add a darker green color */
input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

/* Add a background color and some padding around the form */
.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
  <form >

    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <select id="country" name="country">
      <option value="australia">Australia</option>
      <option value="canada">Canada</option>
      <option value="usa">USA</option>
    </select>

    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitBtn">
  </form>
  </div>
  <table style="width:100%"  id = "myTable">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>country</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: THANKS FOR YOUR SUPPORT but   I want add the data inside the table  your code is posting data outside the table any suggestions

Comment: Thanks it works  fine can we adjust the alignment inside the table

Comment: @m.dvenkatesh to adjust alignment just add `td { text-align: center; }` to your css styles.